# How to create an "add_filter" function if "filter name" is in the form of "$filter" in apply_filters?

Tags: php, wordpress, bbpress

In the following WP php code:

```
function bbp_get_topic_post_count( $topic_id = 0, $integer = false ) {
        $topic_id = bbp_get_topic_id( $topic_id );
        $replies  = (int) get_post_meta( $topic_id, '_bbp_reply_count', true ) + 1;
        $filter   = ( true === $integer ) ? 'bbp_get_topic_post_count_int' : 'bbp_get_topic_post_count';

        return apply_filters( $filter, $replies, $topic_id );
    }
```

I would like to change "$replies" by using filters. Since there is "apply_filters" above, I think it's possible to add "add_filter". But it seems that the filter name is "$filter"

```
function bbp_reply_count_modified( $replies, $topic_id ) {
            $topic_id = bbp_get_topic_id( $topic_id );
            $replies  = (int) get_post_meta( $topic_id, '_bbp_reply_count', true ); // deleted '+ 1'
            return $replies;
add_filter( '___________________', 'bbp_reply_count_modified', 10, 2 );
```

In this case, how can I create an "add_filter" function?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter name, **based on the methods second parameter** `$integer`, is either `bbp_get_topic_post_count_int` (when `$integer` is `true`) or `bbp_get_topic_post_count` (when `$integer` is `false`, which is the default parameter value of `$integer`, if there isn't a value for it at method call).

The value of `$filter` is assigned here:

```
$filter = ( true === $integer ) ? 'bbp_get_topic_post_count_int' : 'bbp_get_topic_post_count';
```

Therefore, you don't need to modify the method, but should search for usage of the method to see which input parameter for $integer is given.

To use the filter for **$integer = true**, use:

```
add_filter( 'bbp_get_topic_post_count_int', 'bbp_get_topic_post_count', 10, 2 );
```

To use the filter for **$integer = false**, use:

```
add_filter( 'bbp_get_topic_post_count', 'bbp_get_topic_post_count', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: I resolved this issue. (In my code in my question, only the filter name needs to be corrected to "bbp_get_topic_post_count.") Thanks again for your kind answer.